# Get PID of process started in screen by su

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, gnu-screen, pid

i have a simple script that starts quassel-core in a screen session as different user!
The script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
su ircc -c 'screen -dmS quassel /home/ircc/quassel/quassel-core'
```

I want to start and stop this in an debian init.d script using start-stop-daemon
What is the best way to get the PID of quassel-core (or of the screen, that should work too) and store it in a file?
At the moment i use:

```
pidof quassel-core > /var/run/quasselcore.pid
```

but that will fail if some other user starts quassel-core.

Comment: `pgrep -u ircc -f quassel-core`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are happy just to kill a named screen session belonging to your user, and not really interested in the pid. In that case, with a screen named "`quassel`", you can run

```
screen -S quassel -X quit
```

which as per the manual will

> Kill all windows and terminate screen.

Only screens owned by you are affected.

Answer (score 3):

In the `procps` package (or something similarly named, depending on distribution) you can find `pgrep`:

> pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout.

So in your case:

```
pgrep -u josef quassel-core
```

should give you a list of the process IDs belonging to currently running `quassel-core` processes started by the `josef` user.

In the package you also get `pkill` which kills a process based on a similar search process, so you wouldn't really need a pid file if this is all you are going to use it for.

---

All that said: if you use `start-stop-daemon`, you can use the `--pidfile` switch to start the process. See `man start-stop-daemon` for usage.

Comment: +1 This is a good way to go, similar method using ps: ps -U <user> | grep <process_name> | awk '{print $1}'

Comment: the --pidfile option doesn't work, because it will store the pid of the su process which will instantly exit after running screen!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the PID of the process running in screen, I answered that [in another question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28395244/343302). Here is the contents of that answer:

You can get the PID of the screen sessions here like so:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
        1934.foo_Server         (01/25/15 15:26:01)     (Detached)
        1876.foo_Webserver      (01/25/15 15:25:37)     (Detached)
        1814.foo_Monitor        (01/25/15 15:25:13)     (Detached)
3 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-ubuntu.
```

Let us suppose that you want the PID of the program running in Bash in the `foo_Monitor` screen session. Use the PID of the `foo_Monitor` screen session to get the PID of the `bash` session running in it by searching PPIDs (Parent PID) for the known PID:

```
$ ps -el | grep 1814 | grep bash
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1000  1815  1814  0  80   0 -  5520 wait   pts/1    00:00:00 bash
```

Now get just the PID of the `bash` session:

```
$ ps -el | grep 1814 | grep bash | awk '{print $4}'
1815
```

Now we want the process with *that* PID. Just nest the commands, and this time use the `-v` flag on `grep bash` to get the process that is *not* bash:

```
echo $(ps -el | grep $(ps -el | grep 1814 | grep bash | awk '{print $4}') | grep -v bash | awk '{print $4}')
23869
```

**Just replace 1814 with the real PID of your screen session:**

```
echo $(ps -el | grep $(ps -el | grep SCREEN_SESSION_PID | grep bash | awk '{print $4}') | grep -v bash | awk '{print $4}')
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more trying, here is my own solution:

```
screen -list | grep quassel | cut -f1 -d'.' | sed 's/\W//g'
```

It reads the pid of the screen with the name "quassel"
Seems to be the safest way to me.

Thanks also to Daniel Andersson, this should work too.

start-stop-daemons --pidfile is of no use, because it doesn't create the pidfile! With -m it would store the pid of the screen started, but screen seems to fork itself on start, so the pid changes!

Comment: `screen -list | awk '/quassel/{print substr($1,0,index($1,".")-1)}'` is fewer forks and "nicer". But see separate answer if you just want to kill a named screen session.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
ps -ef | grep quassel-cor[e] | awk '{print $2}' > /var/run/quasselcore.pid
```

This assumes that there is only one such process running. If that is not true you need to further refine your grep.

Comment: Instead of `grep` you could use `awk '/quassel-core/{print $2}' directly. `ps` is not really meant to be used for processing like this, though; it is more of a presentation layer and can give unwanted results when trying to be processed (such as including the matching process itself among the matches). Better is to use a tool designed for searching through `/proc` in a more strict manner. In this case this is noticed since Josef wants to match on user name as well, and the matching soon gets tedious this way.